# Should I worry on the contents of a Richtext editor before saving to database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, richtextbox

**A simple input/output goes:**

[image]

*After saving to **DB**, I see these large texts:*

[image]

1. **Is my approach good? If not, please correct me.**
2. **Do I have to upload the image(s)?**

Answer (score 2):

You have to worry all user inputs. Sanitize.

The images depend on where they are from. Are users inserting images from a predefined list? If yes then you can add some logics to just save the reference. Application specific.

I am not sure how the image becomes base64. Normally images will be links. Then saving links are trivial. Saving base64 encoded takes up lots of database storage. And other performance issues. Imagine one entry has many images?

Other performance issues depends on your application. Is it web based or mobile? User transmitting in this form choke up large bandwidth on mobile. Imagine submitting a form of textarea requires user to Upload megabytes depending on the number of images.

If saving the images to your own system is important, you can consider storing as public accessible files in s3 or otherwise. Then link to them.

Comment: So, what I'm seeing right now is an example of a BLOB data?

Comment: Nope. BLOB (Binary Large OBject) or CLOB (Character Large OBject). The image data is base64 encoded which is a string.

Comment: Alright. I'm kinda woried on the large texts though.

Comment: @PeterWateber what's Your table column type

Comment: @ripa richtext (text) latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: it's better to define "mediumtext"

Comment: Medium text may not work. It can holds up to 16mb. We do not know how many or how big the images are. Probably have to redesign.

Answer (score 1):

With Rich Text Editors, you need to sanitize the HTML prior to saving it to the database.  Otherwise, your site is vulnerable to cross-site scripting(XSS) attacks because an attacker could inject JavaScript into the page in [a variety of different ways](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

To prevent against this, use a well-tested HTML sanitation library (do NOT roll out you're own!).  Some good sanitation libraries are:

- PHP: [htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php), [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)
- Java: [Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project)
- .NET: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [Anti XSS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXss/)
- Pure JavaScript Impelementations: [DOM Purify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify), [Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)

Answer (score 0):

you should blacklist stuff like iframe as it can be used for XSS attacks.

check : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

What users put in, is what other users see. That is one reason to sanitize. You probably don't want to serve web pages which contain malware.

The other reason to sanitize is your own server. Always Worry about script and SQL injection attacks.